# how to use jQuery on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scope

Before anything, I wish to clarify my coming question by saying that I have just been out of a "function not defined" problem, which was solved by moving the desired function to "head". (I still find it strange the onclick couldn't see the function in its own file...)
I am 1/2 day old to jQuery. I have a CSS'd list(A), the html that builds the list (B) and a jQuery function (C) that processes the collapsing/expanding of the list. All borrowed from here:

jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/GpdgF/

When all this is in one file, it works fine. But when this file is read into a div, it doesn't work anymore. I've been trying moving A and C around a while now, because I think it is something I don't know about the scope (or related issues) of something here:) and needless to say, the collapsing/expanding/hovering is not yet happening. If I MUST have the html code (B) in a yet-to-be-loaded file, do I keep the A and B parts in this file, or do I place them in the  of my main page (that contains the div which will eventually hold B), or something else?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: nothing here makes any sense.  what does a tree view have to do with multiple HTML pages?

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I'm looking for. Once I load all that, that is in file X into a div that already exists, on page Y, the hover/collapsing etc don't work anymore, So I thought I'm having a scope problem, but might be something else that I'm unaware of. (like a js function that worked perfectly well but stopped doing so once I had a jQuery function just above it, in the same "script" tag...)

Comment: your comment doesn't make any more sense than the body of the question.  how could a control on page X affect something on page Y, when you can only load one HTML page at a time?

Comment: Main page has a left div (menu, not relevant) and the right div where content change as we do stuff. When that list is implemented (loaded as-is) into the right div, the jQuery part doesn't work,

Comment: so are these iframes then?

Comment: nope. Just divs. Maybe another way to put the question would be: Some element whose functionality depends on a jQuery function, is in a file X that will be loaded into a div in a certain  main page Y. Why isn't my jQuery working when I place it in X, or at the "head" of Y, etc, but works fine when all are in one file,

Comment: it's not really possible to hold a conversation through comments trying to ask you more information until we understand your problem.  You really should consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then editing your question, preferably with code samples and desired vs actual behavior.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Right... I had found the downvotes strange... you guys almost gave me a sad birthday :P turns out the issue wasn't understandable till you fall in the trap. Found the solution in one of these obscure web places ;)

Here you go:
Somehow pages loaded into other pages through certain methods (ajax being one?) get stripped of their "calling the javascript" capabilities. I had:

main page  --> | div 1 on left | div 2 on right|

Stuff gets loaded into div 2 depending on actions taken on div 1 or div 2 itself. This means in my case that whatever is loaded into div 2 ALSO needs javascript capabilities for the decision taking.

a random page X.htm---> |html+css+js|

(this one being one of various "pages" that could be loaded in DIV 2 in main page)

html works ok, css works ok, js doesn't work AT ALL, never ever. Not even SEEN by anyone? Dunno why...

SOLUTION:

1) put the JS relevant to your child pages in  of main page!
2) put the following at end of any page loaded into DIV 2, like "page X" above

```
<img src="oneTransparentPixel.png" onload="theFunctionWeNeedInPageX()" />
```

Where you create a 1 pixel transparent image to be loaded (!). The hack here is that the loading of the image allows for the calling of the function we need...

I don't know if the JS code is unseen if in the child page, or not executed, or the page isn't yet ready to execute it. Whatever the case, this "solution" allows for
1) code is now seen
2) it is executed once the page is ready to let the function do the stuff it should. In my case the function stylizes the mouse over/collapsing/etc of a list in the child page X. So it *might* have been that the code was not yet ready to be applied on the list because the list didn't yet exist - was not rendered by the browser, or because the code was not being seen by anyone. Could someone clarify what was happening, or point us to what to read so we know?
Thank you for your time :)